# Set datatable column width (lightning community)

Tags: javascript, datatable, salesforce, salesforce-lightning

I would like to set a fixed width on the first column for lightning:datatable

I have already tried adding a initialWidth property to a column but it did not work. Adding `.THIS tr :first-child {width: 800px !important;}`  in CSS file did set custom witdh on the column but it gets overlapped by the next column. My idea is that the style gets overridden by salesforce in the rendering phase. Therefore I tried to set it in the Renderer.js in afterRender function but I can't get it to work. Here is the code I wrote so far

```
   afterRender: function (component, helper) {
        this.superAfterRender();
        var table = document.getElementById('subscriptionsTable');
        var rows = table.getElementsByTagName('tr');
        for (var i=0; i<rows.length; i++) {
            rows[i].firstChild.style.width = '810px !important';
        }
```

If you have any other ideas on how to achieve a custom column width please let me know. Thanks